# Close the whole tabpanel when there are no child panel

Tags: extjs6

I have a tabpanel and have many childs. Each are closable. I want to remove the tabpanel itself when there are no children.

```
listeners: {
    close: function(element) {
        var detailTabPanel = element.up('DetailTabPanel');
        if(detailTabPanel.items.length <= 1)
        {
           detailTabPanel.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

I have written code like above for close action. But i get error like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null DetailTabPanel is the tabpanel.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there! Try it like this:

```
listeners: {
    remove: function(tabpanel, child, eOpts) {
        if (tabpanel.items.length === 0) {
            tabpanel.destroy();   
        }
    }
}
```

See Fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fo2

You don't have to do `callParent` inside a listener.

Comment: The tabpanel is still in the process of removing the tab and updating its layout. Deferring the removal of the tabpanel a tiny bit seems to solve that.
Two changes: 1) I've changed `destroy` to `close`. Destroy is often a bit forceful and close allows for a cleaner remove, firing `close` events. 2) I've placed the tabpanel inside a container panel, to prevent the entire viewport from being removed.

Comment: I've worked the changes i mentioned above into the Fiddle example

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong event. Rather than listening for the `close` event of the children (which is called after the tab is removed from the panel), you want to listen for the [`remove`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0-classic/Ext.tab.Panel.html#event-remove) event on the tab panel itself.

Comment: listeners: {
        remove: function(element , component , eOpts) {
            if(element.items.length === 0)
            {
                element.destroy();
                element.callParent();
            }
        }
    }  I tried the above code and still i get error like Uncaught Error: this.callParent() was called but there's no such method (fire) found in the parent class (Ext.Base)